# Make a coupon so that a certain product is free including the tax

Tags: magento, coupon

I have created a shopping cart rule in Magento so that I can sell coupon codes and have the product free including shipping. I did this, If an item is FOUND in the cart with ALL of these conditions true: 
Category is 65 
Quantity in cart is 1 
Row total in cart is 22.99 
Then I did a fixed amount discount of 22.99 under actions, but it still charges tax on the item. Any idea how to not charge tax to a item that is now free?
I don't want customers to get the whole cart free just this item with their coupon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a setting in the tax configuration rather than the coupon configuration.

System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Tax -> Calculation Settings

You need to make sure the tax is applied after the discount has been made. Note that it is actually a legal requirement to set it up like this in some countries, for example in the UK you will get a rap on the knuckles from HMRC if you are making a tax calculation on an amount which is subsequently discounted.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Healed my headache

Comment: Excellent.  And welcome to Stackoverflow.  Also, be aware there is a dedicated stack for Magento at http://magento.stackexchange.com/ which will help soothe your sore Magento head with a lot of sage advice from some very generous Magento developers.